# How to discard innerText between certain elements using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, element, isolate

I am writing a webpage scraper to collate sentences in Japanese. My source utilises so-called furigana, which appears as characters above kanji to indicate the Kanji's pronunciation. I do not want this furigana to appear in my scraped sentences.

The website's source html looks something like (source: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10014010651000/k10014010651000.html):

```
<article class = "article-main">
<p>
<span class="colorB">16</span><span class="color4"><ruby>日<rt>にち</rt></ruby></span>
<span class="colorB">、</span><span class="colorL"><ruby>韓国<rt>かんこく</rt></ruby
</span>
</p>
</article>
```

Which shows the characters between にち above the character 日 and かんこく above 韓国.

I current scrape the article-main element, and use get_attribute("innerText") to separate the article text, as follows:

```
element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "article-main")
article = element.get_attribute("innerText")
print(article)
```

However this outputs the furigana after the kanji within the sentences, so I end up with an output that looks like 16日にち、韓国かんこく instead of 16日、韓国. How can I remove the contents between ?

I have tried finding "rt" tag names, and replacing with "" as below:

```
element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "article-main")
html = element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
furigana = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "rt")
print(element.innerText.replace(furigana.innerText, ''))
```

But, the Webelement object has no innerText attribute. What approach can I take to isolate and remove the rt elements using Python?

Comment: Try `browser.execute_script("arguments[0].remove()", furigana)`, then read `element.get_attribute("innerText")`

Comment: Assuming I understood you correctly: `element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "article-main")
html = element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(html)
furigana = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "rt")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].remove()", furigana)
print(element.get_attribute("innerText")) `returns an error "Javascript error: arguments[0].remove is not a function"

Comment: Can you print out what `furigana` is before that?

Comment: The result from the console looks like `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="62e3dded44ae014b22a654d4de88677c", element="20d78c31-128d-4ef5-ac49-f9b271f2b004")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="62e3dded44ae014b22a654d4de88677c"......`

Comment: Ok, try `browser.execute_script("for(const el of arguments[0]) el.remove();", furigana)`

Comment: `furigana = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "rt")
browser.execute_script("for(const el of arguments) el.remove();", furigana)
print(element.get_attribute("innerText"))` now returns the error "javascript error: el.remove is not a function"

Comment: Replace `arguments` with `arguments[0]`. I edited my comment above.

Comment: That worked - thank you! May I ask for a brief explanation of the code please?

Comment: I've posted that as an answer now. Essentially, `furigana` is passed as the first argument to the script (`arguments[0]`). Then, we loop over each element in that array with `for...of`, using `.remove()` to delete each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to remove each of the `<rt>` elements.

```py
furigana = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "rt")
browser.execute_script("for (const el of arguments[0]) el.remove();", furigana)
```

After that, you can read the `innerText` of the element.

```py
article = element.get_attribute("innerText")
```